# Sysmgr volatile memory bug

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios

As you may know that there is a bug with Nexus switches called `SYSMGR-2-VOLATILE_DB_FULL` with versions below `System version: 5.0(2)N2(1)` that causes a switch to crash reboot once dir `/dev/shm` gets to 100% unless updated to a later version.

in order to fill the dir you can run long commands such as `"show run"` (needs to be over 190 lines) and then check how it increases by running

```
show system internal flash
show system internal dir /dev/shm | i csm_acfg | count
```

I was wondering if there is a similar bug with 4500 switches ?

`Catalyst 4500 L3 Switch Software (cat4500es8-UNIVERSALK9-M), Version 03.11.00.E RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc3)`

So what exactly happened...

I have a script that runs from time to time that gets over 190 lines from all of our switches and performs some action remotely, so recently when the script ran a few minutes later we had a massive outage since our core switch had a power outage( at least what I was able to see from the logs) The thing is there are 2 4500 chassis configured with sso redundancy so the failover should have been instantaneous, however everything was down for about 8 mins before the standby switch became active.

Can anyone please advise if there is a similar bug with 4500 switches ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After analysing crash info I was able to find some things that caused the crash, however wont be able to tell with 100 % certainty what exactly happened to crash it

So there are a few errors that are called VFETQINTERRUPT and VFETQTOOMANYPARITYERRORS basically VFETQINTERRUPT counts fast accruing errors and VFETQTOOMANYPARITYERRORS will crash reboot switch if exceeds 100 errors in a short period of time, could indicate that there is a hardware error

and this is pretty much what happened in out environment, something has caused 100+ errors and it crashed rebooted.

There is a command to stop it from crash rebooting, however not sure if it should be used as if there is a hardware issue it better to failover onto the other supervisor.

`platform fw-asic dbl hash memory parity-error reload never`